# How to install BeautifulSoup4 for Python 2.7 while also having Python 3.4 installed?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have both Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.4.1 installed on my Windows 8.1 system. I had installed `BeautifulSoup4` with pip to run a code (not mine). However, pip automatically installed bs4 to Python 3.4.1. (I checked that it was installed in `C://Python34/lib/site-packages/bs4`)

I have use the command prompt, change directory to C:\Python27 (where Python 2.7 is installed), and pip install bs4 from that directory, but it didn't work. I had copied the bs4 folder from Python 3.4, but it didn't work either. It only gave another Import Error: No module named html.entities.

How can I install bs4 on Python 2.7? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can run `pip2 install bs4` and `pip3 install bs4` to install them separately on different python versions

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I had never known there was the command 'pip2' or 'pip3'. :)